# Copy entries in table changing one field

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a table with entries for suppliers and items. I need to copy some of these entries for one supplier into the same table but for another supplier

I have:

```
Supplier     Product     Price
SupplierA    ProductA    123
SupplierA    ProductB    123
SupplierA    ProductC    123
```

and I want to copy these entries to change the table to

```
Supplier     Product     Price
SupplierA    ProductA    123
SupplierA    ProductB    123
SupplierA    ProductC    123
SupplierB    ProductA    123
SupplierB    ProductB    123
SupplierB    ProductC    123
```

Comment: OK, so what have you tried and what did you get stuck with?

Comment: I had been playing around with various insert into select statements but couldn't work out how to change the entries, but the answer below helped me thanks

Comment: Then include those attempts in your question, @GordonCopestake .

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
insert into suppliers (Supplier, product, price)
select 'SupplierB', product, price 
from suppliers
where Supplier = 'SupplierA'
```